# Table View alert does not show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following code in a UITableViewController:

```
#import "TaskTableController.h"
@implementation TaskTableController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Pineapple",@"Banana",nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [theArray count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected a row" message:[theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [theArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

The problem is when I click on a cell, it highlights the cell but does not ever show the alert. Is there something that I am missing? Inside FirstView I have a tableview the tableview looks at the tableview object that's class is set to TaskTableController.

Comment: it seems you had not assign 'delegate' of UITableView in your FirstView, you had only attach, 'datasource',

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to set delegate UITableViewDelegate with FileOwner.